# glib, portable and readable time

Tags: glib

I am trying to get time with microseconds through glib which will work on windows too, if possible.

My approach:

```
     char buff[256];
     GTimeVal mtime;
     g_get_current_time(&mtime);
     strftime(buff, sizeof(buff), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%%06u", mtime);
     printf("%s\n", buff);
```

... don't work as expected.

What to do to get this working?

Thanks.

[Edit]
Second example:

```
GTimeVal start, finish;
g_get_current_time(&start);

//some operation

g_get_current_time(&finish);

GTimeVal el;
el.tv_sec = finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
el.tv_usec = finish.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
if (el.tv_usec < 0)
{
    el.tv_usec += 1000000;
    el.tv_sec--;
}

char st[24] = {0};
char qt[32] = {0};
if (counter)
{
    sprintf(st, "%s%d%s", "   Finded ", counter, " results");
    sprintf(qt, " %u.%06u %s", (guint)el.tv_sec, (guint)el.tv_usec, " sec");
}
```

Comment: What is your expectation and what does it do differently than your expectation?

Comment: I simply trying to get portable, reliable and precise measuring of time needed for operation (and other purposes). I can get it on linux but in windows (also with gtk) this seems don't work properly. Is this true or my programming isn't good enough?

Comment: You need to say _what_ isn't working and _how_ you know that it's not working. Your second code example doesn't reveal anything more than your first one - they're just two code samples that use `g_get_current_time()`.

Comment: Well, first example don't work at all so probably my code is not good but second, which measures db query time gives on linux value 0.142562 while in windows it gives 1524126982.254264 what is not correct because similar time ealpses.

Comment: The first example doesn't work because `GTimeVal` is not `struct tm`, which is required by `strftime()`. As for the second example, why don't you try printing out the members of `start` and `end` directly just to verify that they make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best shot for portability may be to drop `GTimeVal`, which is deprecated in glib, for `GDateTime` and related functions.  (`g_date_time_format()` in place of `strftime()`, `g_date_time_new_now()` in place of `g_get_current_time()`).

Comment: How can you print microseconds with `g_date_time_format()`?